# With selenium I do not get the data

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have with successfully navigated to an iframe with selenium + phantomJS but I do not get the data.

If I look the [iframe url](http://ebelediye.fatih.bel.tr/alfa/servlet/hariciprogramlar.online.rayiclist?RUHSAT_YILI=2017&ISMAH_KOD=0&ISSK_KOD=999&AKTARMA=%27AKTARMA%27) in Midori browser I can see the result.
But with webdriver without the table.

Here is my test code:

```
link = 'http://ebelediye.fatih.bel.tr/alfa/servlet/hariciprogramlar.online.rayic?caid=1449'

def get_site():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    driver.get(link)
    driver.find_element_by_name('btnlistele').click()
    src = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe').get_attribute('src')
    driver.get(src)
    print driver.page_source
```

Answer (score -1):

This seem to be security issue, because of the high frequency you're sending requests.

> FloodGuard Güvenlik uyarısı !!! 
>   Bu kadar sık istek gönderemezsiniz !!!

Just add some delay as below:

```
import time

link = 'http://ebelediye.fatih.bel.tr/alfa/servlet/hariciprogramlar.online.rayic?caid=1449'

def get_site():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_name('btnlistele').click()
    src = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe').get_attribute('src')
    driver.get(src.replace('ISSK_KOD=', 'ISSK_KOD=999'))
    print driver.page_source
```

Comment: It have nothing doing with the timing. While If I ask directly the iframe src, I become noting data's as answer using selenium.

Comment: eg. this is the url of 1 iframe: http://ebelediye.fatih.bel.tr/alfa/servlet/hariciprogramlar.online.rayiclist?RUHSAT_YILI=2017&ISMAH_KOD=0&ISSK_KOD=999&AKTARMA=%27AKTARMA%27 and using selenium I become just empty site with hidden fields without datas.

Comment: Yes, I have it previously tried before I post a question.

Comment: The content of `iframe` is not displayed in `Chrome` as well as in `Firefox`. Is not a `Selenium` issue. With my code I can get `HTML` source of `iframe`. If it;s not what you want, then add more details to your question

Comment: @vatay, ok. I got your point. The problem is that `src` of `iframe` is not equal to http://ebelediye.fatih.bel.tr/alfa/servlet/hariciprogramlar.online.rayiclist?RUHSAT_YILI=2017&ISMAH_KOD=0&ISSK_KOD=999&AKTARMA=%27AKTARMA%27... it has empty `ISSK_KOD` parameter. so you need to use this line `src.replace('ISSK_KOD=', 'ISSK_KOD=999')`. Try updated code